# Parsing XML with DataSet- Performance

Tags: c#, xml

As per my requirement I want to display some product related information into my UI.

All the information's come through one API URL.API Return XML Output. XML may have more than 100 tag. But as per my requirement I want only 30 to 50 tag. Here I need to pass parameter as input and get the product information.

I using .asmx service as wrapper service and all the parsing process are done here.

In code behind page, I consume the service and display the information.

How to parse the XML? Currently I planned to do is XML to DataSet-(ds.ReadXml(XML))

Does it affect performance? Is there any other way to do? Please guide me.

Comment: `System.Xml.Linq` and XDocument can be a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

I would  use `LINQ to XML`

more info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

for older version of the framework use the `XmlTextReader`

*Use the XmlTextReader class to process large XML documents in an efficient, forward - only manner. XmlTextReader uses small amounts of memory
Avoid using the DOM because the DOM reads the entire XML document into memory. If the entire XML document is read into memory, the scalability of your application is limited. Using XmlTextReader in combination with an XmlTextWriter class permits you to handle much larger documents than a DOM-based XmlDocument class.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind the result to a Control, then dataset approach (indicated by you) makes sense. How ever, if you need text value of those 30 / 50 tags without what the parent/child nodes are in between, you can use XmlDocument/XPath

Comment: Yes i want to bind it into controls.i have created two projects 1.web app 2.wrapper service. wrapper service will consume api and readxml into dataset.it will return dataset to web app.here i doing bind it into controls.my way is correct?